# aws modify reserved instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Have an issue with AWS python boto3 call `ec2.meta.client.modify_reserved_instances()`.

I am getting the error below:

> botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
>   Unknown parameter in TargetConfigurations[0]: "Scope", must be one of: AvailabilityZone, Platform, InstanceCount, InstanceType

This is my function:

```
def modify_reserved_instance(self, region, iid, icount, itype):
    ec2 = boto3.resource(
    'ec2', region_name=region[:-1], api_version='2016-04-01')

    response = ec2.meta.client.modify_reserved_instances(
    ClientToken='string',
    ReservedInstancesIds=[
    iid,
    ],
    TargetConfigurations=[
    {
    'AvailabilityZone': region,
    'Platform': 'Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)',
    'InstanceCount': icount,
    'InstanceType': itype,
    'Scope': 'Availability Zone'
    },
    ]
    )
    print (response)
    return response
```

I have tried the Scope as `AvailabilityZone` and `Availability Zone`.

- Updated botocore: `sudo pip install botocore --upgrade`
- Installed boto3/botocore from github: `https://github.com/boto/boto3`

Has anyone else used the method from `boto3.resource('ec2')` object?

Comment: While not obviously related to the error message (which indicates that the space in the string definitely needs to be removed), this seems wrong: `{ 'AvailabilityZone': region, ... }` A region is not the same thing as an availability zone. For example, `us-west-2` is a region, `us-west-2c` is an availability zone within the region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [boto3 documentation for `modify_reserved_instance()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_reserved_instances) shows parameters as:

- **AvailabilityZone:** eg `us-west-2c`
- **Platform:** Either EC2-Classic or EC2-VPC
- **InstanceCount**
- **InstanceType**
- **Scope:** `standard` or `convertible`

Your error message says that **boto3 does not recognise the `Scope` parameter**.

It is **not** saying that the Scope parameter should be set to "AvailabilityZone, Platform, InstanceCount, InstanceType" -- they are simply a list of parameters that it is **expecting** (and Scope isn't one of them).

Convertible Reserved Instances [became available in September 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-reserved-instance-update-convertible-ris-and-regional-benefit/). It would appear that your local copy of `boto3` is out-of-date.

I suggest you update your version of `boto3` to a version that knows the Scope parameter:

```
sudo pip install boto3 --upgrade
```

Comment: This was my issue api_version='2016-04-01'